# How to avoid ranking by date in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am stuck on a problem, for which I can not get a work around. In my tableau chart, I have to calculate rank (Top) based on charge type, so here is what I did
[Rank by Charge type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmiwo.png)
Now i have to calculate such rank for weeks (ranging from one date to another) 
so I dragged date into column like this [Weekly Rank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lgvq.png)
Now, my rank order has become improper and it is giving me rank for a single day.

How can I avoid ranking based on date? I simply want rank to be calculated on charge type, irrespective of the date, for a range of dates. (Please do not get alarmed by lack of pics)

Answer (score 0):

Does using index() instead of rank(sum[Charge Amt]) work? Then calculate index by Charge Type, make sure it is discrete.

Comment: I actually tried it in the first place, but index are not getting computed by charge type as I am not getting any option to compute using charge type

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an LOD expression may help. Something like this: {FIXED [Charge Type]: rank(sum[Charge Amt] }